# Can fetch website in CURL but not in Nodejs Request

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, request, request-promise

I'm trying to fetch a page from IMDB, but for some odd reason it gives me error 400 when I'm using `request-promise`

But the same query works fine if I'm using CURL:

curl "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6306064/mediaviewer/rm3146075904"

My nodejs code:

```
async function getMoviePosterImage(mediaViewerUrl) {
  const options = {
    uri: mediaViewerUrl
  };
  try {
    const mediaViewerHtml = await request.get(options);

    return mediaViewerHtml;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.statusCode);
  }
}

  await getMoviePosterImage(
    "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6306064/mediaviewer/rm3146075904"
  );
```

Things I have tried so far:

- Setting a user agent
- Setting keep-alive
- Having cookie jar enabled

Comment: Can you write out the error that you're getting? Also, any reason why you can't use request-promise-native?

Comment: I can't really write out the whole error code, because it's basically just a big printout of the response object with statuscode 400, and imdb html saying the request could not be understood.There's not really any reason I can't use request-promise-native, but I think I have even tried with just regular request also, but will try again. I'm just using request-promise because it seems to have been working for me so far.

Comment: Same with regular request as well

Comment: imdb 400 error html: https://pastebin.com/dhEcFn26 response object: https://pastebin.com/iHgdMFjs

Comment: I have a feeling that IMDB doesn't like web scrapers... just tried it locally and the same error happened to me

Comment: Thank you, good to know I'm not the only one, I guess I will leave it for now then. I'll accept that comment as an answer if you make one :-)

Comment: Haha sounds good 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my end, I just tried locally and the same error happened for me. Not a definitive answer, but I have a feeling that IMDB protects against web scrapers.